# How do I get .NET's Path.Combine to convert forward slashes to backslashes?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Path.Combine like so:

```
Path.Combine("test1/test2", "test3\\test4");
```

The output I get is:

```
test1/test2\test3\test4
```

Notice how the forward slash doesn't get converted to a backslash. I know I can do string.Replace to change it, but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Is the backslash a problem? The .NET and Windows file APIs accept either.

Comment: What is the problem with the mixed slashes? Vanity?

Comment: @John, yes there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx. Or were you trying to be pedantic about the difference between C# and .NET?

Comment: @JS: yes, I was being pedantic about the difference between C# and .NET. There are far too many people who don't seem to get the difference.

Comment: @John: Thanks for pointing that out. I should've said .NET instead of C#, but given how 99% of the time I'm using C# with .NET, I considered them one and the same.

Comment: @Daniel: one of the practical benefits of the separation is that one can use C# 3.0 features in a .NET 2.0 application.

Comment: @John I am missing how that is relevant I think.  I don't think Path.Combine is specific to C# 3.0 or see that the question was scoped to .NET 2.0.  Otherwise I would be onboard.  If Daniel were a beginner unfamiliar with the difference, I think "There is no Path.Combine in C#" would have just introduced more confusion, because it a very incomplete thought and doesn't really make any kind of point other than to say "You are wrong, I know something you don't, and I will allude to that, but not elaborate on it enough to help enlighten you or contribute in any meaningful way to this discussion."

Comment: @AaronLS: Thanks for pointing that out in such a timely manner. It was over two years ago.

Comment: @John No problem.  Glad it was met with appreciation.  Never too late to grow.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because your "test1/test2" is already a string literal, Path.Combine will not change the '/' for you to a '\'.

Path.Combine will only concat the 2 string literals with the appropriate path delimiter used by the OS, in this case Windows, which is '\', from there your output

```
test1/test2\test3\test4
```

Your best bet would be the string.Replace.

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively, I found out that `Path.GetFullPath()` will also replace slashes with backslashes.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that, but I will sure make a note of it.

Comment: After the combine, you could probably replace ALL types of slashes with `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`.

Answer (score 140):

As others have said, Path.Combine doesn't change the separator.
However if you convert it to a full path:

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("test1/test2", "test3\\test4"))
```

the resulting fully qualified path will use the standard directory separator (backslash for Windows).

Note that this works on Windows because both \ and / are legal path separators:

```
Path.DirectorySeparatorChar = \
Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar = /
```

If you run on, say, .NET Core 2.0 on Linux, only the forward slash is a legal path separator:

```
Path.DirectorySeparatorChar = /
Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar = /
```

and in this case it won't convert backslash to forward slash, because backslash is not a legal alternate path separator.

Comment: Works but be careful as GetFullPath() will fix up relative paths and turn it into full paths. If you need to retain a relative path GetFullPath() won't work.

Comment: @George, are you sure: mono on which OS?  What is the standard path separator for your version of mono (Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)?

Comment: @Joe unfortunately yes. Mono JIT compiler version 5.8.0.108 (2017-10/9aa78573ee2 Wed Jan 10 04:30:03 EST 2018) on Mac with System.IO.Path version: Type: System.IO.Path
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Answer (score 26):

Try using the `Uri` class. It will create valid Uris for the correct target machine (`/` -> `\`).

Comment: Well, this works. Just need to create `new Uri(path)` and it automaticaly converts to backslashes. Nice

Comment: Huh. This don't work for me, doing `new Uri("\apath\uploads/filename.png")`. Exception: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. It's in a C# ASP MVC project, .NET v4.5.1. I could've sworn Path.Combine() did this but yeah I guess not.

Answer (score 5):

First, I would argue in this particular case, it wouldn't be unreasonable to do a single .Replace()

Secondly, you could also use System.Uri to format your path, it's very strict. However, this will be more lines than a simple .Replace(). I apperently am voting for you to just use .Replace() be done with it! Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET Reflector, you can see that Path.Combine doesn't change slashes in the provided strings

```
public static string Combine(string path1, string path2)
{
    if ((path1 == null) || (path2 == null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException((path1 == null) ? "path1" : "path2");
    }
    CheckInvalidPathChars(path1);
    CheckInvalidPathChars(path2);
    if (path2.Length == 0)
    {
        return path1;
    }
    if (path1.Length == 0)
    {
        return path2;
    }
    if (IsPathRooted(path2))
    {
        return path2;
    }
    char ch = path1[path1.Length - 1];
    if (((ch != DirectorySeparatorChar) && (ch != AltDirectorySeparatorChar)) && (ch != VolumeSeparatorChar))
    {
        return (path1 + DirectorySeparatorChar + path2);
    }
    return (path1 + path2);
}
```

You can do the same with String.Replace and the Uri class methods to determine which one works best for you.

Comment: Note that `DirectorySeparatorChar = '\\'` and `AltDirectorySeparatorChar = '/'`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var fullname = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine("f:/","test1/test2", "test3\\test4")).FullName;
```

This will result in

```
f:\test1\test2\test3\test4
```

Comment: Maybe on windows, but its not cross platform:

Output:
...bin/Debug/net6.0/f:/test1/test2/test3\test4

Answer (score 0):

If you need your result to have forward slashes instead of backward slashes, and if your first path component is absolute (i.e. rooted) path, you could actually combine it using the `Uri` class:

```
string CombinedPath = new Uri(new Uri("C:/test1/test2"), "test3\\test4").AbsolutePath;
```

Note that this won't work if the first component is relative path too.

Comment: Tried this and it ends up encoding the the backslash to %5C

Comment: Was your path absolute and what version of .Net were you using? For me this worked with .Net Framework, I have not tested with .Net 6.0.

Comment: Linux paths all start with /. But I tried both same result

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Then it seems that the behavior might be OS specific.

Answer (score -1):

No, the seperator character is defined as a Read Only.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.pathseparator.aspx

You should use a Replace as it's a trivial change.

Comment: What are you talking about? Even assuming you mean `DirectorySeparator`, he's trying to change it in his string, not the value used by the system.

Comment: He probably means `.Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)`