# How can I manipulate Windows paths from a Linux app and vice versa in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, cross-platform, path-separator, path-manipulation

I'm building a data transfer tool that may be deployed to either a Windows or Linux Docker container that must instruct SQL Server to take a database snapshot.  Additionally, SQL Server may be on either Windows or Linux and I need to specify where *on the server* the .ss file will go.  I've been using `Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension`, `Path.Combine`, etc but `Path` operations are done in the context of the OS the app is running in.  I need something like WindowsPath.Combine that I can run in Linux when I'm talking to a SQL Server instance on Windows. Right now I do my own string manipulation but I'd prefer to use `Path` or something purpose built if possible.  I know what OS I'm running on and the OS SQL Server is running on and just need an OS agnostic `Path`.

Comment: Related: [How do I get .NET's Path.Combine to convert forward slashes to backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3144492/150605), [.NET path manipulation library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52071/150605)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to make your own class of static functions to do Windows specific path manipulation. "C:\MyDir\MyFile.ext" can actually be the name of a file on Linux.

You can look at various implementations of .NET Path and you can see that it is just using string manipulation:

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/path.cs

I suggest just starting with the methods you need. For example:

```
public static class PathHelper
{
    public static string GetWindowsFileNameWithoutExtension(string filePath)
    {
        int backslashIndex = filePath.LastIndexOf('\\');
        int dotIndex = filePath.LastIndexOf('.');

        if (backslashIndex >= 0 && dotIndex >= 0 && dotIndex > backslashIndex)
        {
            return filePath.Substring(backslashIndex + 1, dotIndex - backslashIndex - 1);
        }

        if (dotIndex >= 0)
        {
            return filePath.Substring(0, dotIndex);
        }

        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
    }
}
```