# How to combine file absolute and relative uri or path?

Tags: c#, .net, path, uri

What I want to implement is a combining function that takes one absolute path/uri and one relative path/uri and returns the two combined. For instance, consider these two paths:

```
var root = "c:\src";
var images = "/images/logo.png" ;
var combined = Combine (root, images); // Either 'c:/src/images/logo.png' or 'c:\src\images\logo.png' is acceptable
```

I want to avoid manually manipulating/intercepting forward and backward slashes and I want to stick to .Net built-in functionalities.
I tried `Uri` and `Path.Combine` but no luck. The biggest problem is that the `images` starts with  a forwarding slash, still I guess there must be a way to tell .Net to treat it as relative to the absolute path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get .NET's Path.Combine to convert forward slashes to backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144492/how-do-i-get-nets-path-combine-to-convert-forward-slashes-to-backslashes)

Comment: @VlaMai The [same problem](https://rextester.com/QWQ48533) presents even if all of the slashes are in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in functionality to do this in the way you want to.

With that in mind, it seems like you should just be able to remove the leading slash:

```
var root = "c:\\src";
var sourceOfImages = "/images/logo.png";
var images = sourceOfImages.TrimStart('/', '\\');
var combined = Path.Combine(root, images);
```

Now this does lead to the output having flashes in differing formats:

> c:\src\images/logo.png

I would suggest using string `Replace` to resolve this:

```
var combined = Path.Combine(root, images).Replace("/", "\\"); // or .Replace("\\", "/");
```

This outputs the path as we would expect:

```
c:\src\images\logo.png
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/HHBZH18699)

Comment: Why is .Net not able to handle this simple scenario? Why do we need to cater for trailing slashes? I want to avoid intercepting/manipulating this as much as possible.

Comment: @Hans I'm not sure, but it certainly seems like deliberate behaviour by `Path.Combine` that it discards "c:\src" when combining the paths normally.